Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement
Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.




We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.
Did I overlook anyone?
Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in no way a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Let's also take a chance to thank these other users for having stepped up to moderate at some point in the past:



Congrats guys!!

Please welcome Artem as our latest addition to the team!

Congrats, Artem!!

So the hunt for the highest flag count just got more exciting! Best of luck Artem! Let the games begin!

@Artem it's good to have you on board on the moderator team.

Welcome @ArnonWeinberg! It took some time, but very glad to finally have you on board! :)

Welcome @ArnonWeinberg. Glad to have you, finally ;-)

Yep, thanks guys, looking forward to it.

Since I have been selected as a Pro Tempore moderator but didn't volunteer initially, I feel I still have to introduce myself to the community.
First off, why didn't I volunteer earlier?
I'm a master student in Game and Media Technology in the Netherlands, currently working on my thesis for which I am creating a user interface (UI) prototype which attempts to alleviate some of the information overload issues known to existing UIs. Meanwhile I work part-time in Belgium as a software developer, and I have a girlfriend who's doing her PhD in England. This makes me a busy person, and I figured other people to be more suitable for the position.
Why did I volunteer?
Aarthi contacted me to reconsider volunteering, based on observations she made which I could describe as "spying" on me, but let's call it "monitoring". ;p

I believe strongly in the Stack Exchange (SE) network and it's goal of "making the internet a better place", borrowing a catchphrase of Jeff Atwood.
I've participated on various sites across the network, not restricting myself to the main sites, but also participating on meta(s).
After one year of Stack Exchange experience I feel I have a good understanding of what it is about, and how I can help in shaping it to become even better. I'm open to any discussion which might result in improved content for the site, even hypothetical discussions which might not be possible at this time.
I might be busy, but my work requires me to be online constantly. This allows me to swiftly respond to/handle flags when I see them. I encourage the community to apply self-moderation, redirecting people to meta or chat where I feel discussion is appropriate.

What do I hope to get out of it?

I committed to the private beta of the Area51 proposal of this site, as I felt it would be a suitable place for me to ask more academic Human Computer Interaction (HCI) research questions. By helping this site along, guiding it out of beta and into a full fledged SE site I hope it to become a useful resource of information for me.
I'm not only interested in HCI research but I've always had an interest in Cognitive Sciences, of which this "to flip or not to flip" question is possible the best example. Less advanced questions are welcomed here on this site, for which I am grateful.
Proper communication is an art, arguably even more so in writing. When you see me making a statement which sounds a bit harsh/incomplete, please correct me, I'm sure I can learn a lot from your feedback. Stack Exchange is community driven, and we can all help making this site great!

I'm honored to take on this role. Thank you for confiding in me!
